# The Terminal executes the first loop and neglets the other loop

Tags: c++, linux

I have a problem in executing my program via terminal.
My program compiles without errors, but executes the for loop while it ignores while loop section. I checked if it executes the while loop section, and yes, it executed successfully without any error(note: to check if it executes the second loop in the program-while loop, I changed the first loop,i.e., for loop block to comments.)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long int p[]={1212121212,3232323232,0404040404};
    char name[5][10]; int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5,j<5;i++,j++)
    { cout<<"\n Enter the Name:";
      cin>>name[i];
    }
    while(j<3)
    { 
    cout<<"\n The Number:"<<p[j];
    j++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Can you please explain what's going on here and how should I sort it out.
Please ignore any misspelled words.

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop condition expression `i<5,j<5`? There is no point in using the `,` operator there. That is just equivalent to writing `j < 5`. If **both** of the sub-expressions must be true for the entire expression to be true, then you must use the `&&` (logical AND) operator. If **at least one** of the sub-expressions must be true, then you should use the `||` (logical OR) operator.

Comment: `i` and `j` have the same value in the first loop.  When the first loop exits, `j` will be `5`.  The second loop will immediately exit, since `5` is not less than `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
for(int i=0;i<5,j<5;i++,j++)
```

You are incrementing `j` until it equals 5, even though you are not using it in the `for` loop.

When the `for` loop ends, `j == 5` which means it is greater than 3, so the code in `while` is never executed - the condition of the loop is never met.

You probably want to remove any use of `j` from the `for` loop, or if there is more code and you need it, remember to reset it to 0 after the `for` loop ends.